# Is it possible to rotate items in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is it possible to rotate items in Quantum GIS Print Composer?

I just didn't found and before submit feature demand just double-check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Item Properties - Rotation. It's available for shapes (rectangles, ellipses, triangle).

Comment: But not for other items, like scale bar?